# How can I use Linq expression for Join with GroupBy in EF Core 3.1

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core, eager-loading, ef-core-3.1

This is my SQL query and I tested it in linqpad, and it worked, but it doesn't work in EF Core 3.1:

```
  from v in JournalVoucherLines
  group v by v.AccountId into vg
  join bp in Parties on vg.FirstOrDefault().AccountId equals bp.AccountId
  select new
  {
    name = bp.FullName,
    key = vg.Key,
    Creditor = vg.Sum(v => v.Credit),
    Deptor = vg.Sum(v => v.Debit),
    RemainAmount = vg.Sum(v => v.Credit) - vg.Sum(v => v.Debit)
  }
```

When I use the query in EF Core, I get this exception:

> The LINQ expression '(GroupByShaperExpression:
> KeySelector: (j.AccountId),
> ElementSelector:(EntityShaperExpression:
> EntityType: JournalVoucherLine
> ValueBufferExpression:
> (ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember)
> IsNullable: False
> )
> ).FirstOrDefault()'
> could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information. "

What is the best practice for this query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, don't use methods like `FirstOrDefault()` on `GroupBy` result - they are not translatable. Use only key(s) and aggregate functions (because that's what SQL `GROUP BY` operator supports).

Second, use temporary projection (`Select`) for `GroupBy` result containing the key/aggregates needed, *then* join it to another entities (tables) to get the additional info needed for the final projection.

e.g.

```cs
from v in JournalVoucherLines
group v by v.AccountId into vg
select new // <-- temporary projection with group by fields needed
{
    AccountId = vg.Key,
    Credit = vg.Sum(v => v.Credit),
    Debit = vg.Sum(v => v.Debit),
} into vg
join bp in Parties on vg.AccountId equals bp.AccountId // <-- additional join(s)
select new
{
    name = bp.FullName,
    key = vg.AccountId,
    Creditor = vg.Credit,
    Deptor = vg.Debit,
    RemainAmount = vg.Credit - vg.Debit
};
```

which translates successfully to

```sql
SELECT [p].[FullName] AS [name], [t].[AccountId] AS [key], [t].[c] AS [Creditor], [t].[c0] AS [Deptor], [t].[c] - [t].[c0] AS [RemainAmount]
FROM (
    SELECT [j].[AccountId], SUM([j].[Credit]) AS [c], SUM([j].[Debit]) AS [c0]
    FROM [JournalVoucherLines] AS [j]
    GROUP BY [j].[AccountId]
) AS [t]
INNER JOIN [Parties] AS [p] ON [t].[AccountId] = [p].[AccountId]
```

**Update:** The same LINQ query with method syntax is even straight forward:

```cs
var query = JournalVoucherLines
    .GroupBy(v => v.AccountId)
    .Select(vg => new
    {
        AccountId = vg.Key,
        Credit = vg.Sum(v => v.Credit),
        Debit = vg.Sum(v => v.Debit),
    })
    .Join(Parties, vg => vg.AccountId, bp => bp.AccountId, (vg, bp) => new
    {
        name = bp.FullName,
        key = vg.AccountId,
        Creditor = vg.Credit,
        Deptor = vg.Debit,
        RemainAmount = vg.Credit - vg.Debit
    });
```

But if you need more joins, query syntax is preferable.

Comment: Hello, Ivan could you please write this query with LINQ Method Syntax?

Comment: Hi @ArminShoeibi, why should I? There are a lot of free tools (or even the debug view) which can show you the equivalent method syntax. Or you can easily do it since there is nothing unusual, e.g. `JournalVoucherLines.GroupBy(v => ...).Select(vg => new { ...}).Join(Parties, vg => ..., p => ..., (vg, p) => new { ...})` etc.

Comment: thank you, what should i search for that tools ?

Comment: Hello, Ivan could you please write this query with LINQ Method Syntax?  i need to..

Comment: @Shahram Here you go.

Comment: tanx  a lot , if we need in   select new { AccountId = vg.Key,..., Voucher = First().Voucher} into vg, ....   and  select new{name = bp.FullName, key = vg.AccountId, VoucherDate = vg.Voucher.VoucherDate,}   , how can i use another way to remove Voucher = First().Voucher

Comment: Nah, no `First()` and similar. See the beginning of the answer - keys and aggregates, nothing else. But you can include the additional fields in the key (even though they won't change the grouping). Or use some aggregate function like `Min` or `Max. Not sure if they are supported for `string`, so better include in the key. This is what people do when writing `GROUP BY` SQL.

Comment: But if you mean this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67474969/is-my-linq-query-optimal-and-high-performance-in-ef-core-3-1, no, navigation property `Voucher` is basically a `Join`, thus cannot be used inside or after `GroupBy` - you should add another manual join in place of that property, and again, *after* `group by` `select into`. EF Core limitation, sorry.