# Is my Linq Query Optimal and High performance in EF Core 3.1?

Tags: entity-framework, linq, eager-loading, ef-core-3.1

can i remove vg.First().Voucher ? and replace the beter code? what is the optimal and best practice?
is convertable this code to another method? like chain method?

```
        var query = from v in _journalLineRepository.TableNoTracking
                .Include(j => j.Voucher).AsEnumerable()
                    group v by v.AccountId into vg
                    select new // <-- temporary projection with group by fields needed
                    {
                        AccountId = vg.Key,
                        Credit = vg.Sum(v => v.Credit),
                        Debit = vg.Sum(v => v.Debit),
                        Voucher = vg.First().Voucher

                    } into vg
                    join p in _partyRepository.TableNoTracking.Include(p => p.PartyPhones).AsEnumerable() on vg.AccountId equals p.AccountId // <-- additional join(s)
                    select new PartyDeptorAndCreditorViewModel
                    {



                        PartyId = p.Id,
                        FullName = p.FullName,
                        PhoneNo = p.PartyPhones.FirstOrDefault(p => p.IsActive)?.Phone,
                        ProjectId = vg.Voucher.ProjectId,
                        AccountId = vg.AccountId.Value,
                        Creditor = vg.Credit,
                        Deptor = vg.Debit,
                        Balance = vg.Credit - vg.Debit,
                        VoucherDate = vg.Voucher.VoucherDate,
                        VoucherRegisterDate = vg.Voucher.VoucherDate,
                        BalanceType =
                            vg.Debit > vg.Credit ? AccountingComplexEnum.ShowPartyBalanceParamSearch.Deptor.ToDisplay(DisplayProperty.Name) :
                            vg.Debit < vg.Credit ? AccountingComplexEnum.ShowPartyBalanceParamSearch.Creditor.ToDisplay(DisplayProperty.Name) :
                             AccountingComplexEnum.ShowPartyBalanceParamSearch.ZeroBalance.ToDisplay(DisplayProperty.Name),

                    };
```

Comment: You should examine the SQL conversion of your query and determine if it is optimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd certainly be looking at the SQL query generated. At face value I see a few warning flags that it may not be composing a query but possibly pre-executing to in-memory processing which would be inefficient.  It would firstly depend on what these `.TableNoTracking` methods/properties return, and the use of `.AsEnumerable` on the eager load joins.

Firstly, when projecting with `Select`, eager load joins (`.Include`) are not necessary. The projections will take care of the joins for you, provided it is projecting down to SQL. If you take out the `.Include().AsEnumerable()` calls and your query still works then it is likely projecting down to SQL. If it is no longer working then it's processing in memory and not efficiently.

Edit: Nope, the inner projection won't resolve: <strike>Regarding the `.Voucher`, your final projection is using 2 fields from this entity, so it stands you could replace this in the initial projection:</strike>

```
                select new // <-- temporary projection with group by fields needed
                {
                    AccountId = vg.Key,
                    Credit = vg.Sum(v => v.Credit),
                    Debit = vg.Sum(v => v.Debit),
                    Voucher = vg.Select(v => new { v.ProjectId, v.VoucherDate }).First()
                } into vg
```

When it comes to transformations like this:

```
BalanceType = vg.Debit > vg.Credit 
    ?        AccountingComplexEnum.ShowPartyBalanceParamSearch.Deptor.ToDisplay(DisplayProperty.Name) 
    : vg.Debit < vg.Credit 
        ? AccountingComplexEnum.ShowPartyBalanceParamSearch.Creditor.ToDisplay(DisplayProperty.Name) 
        : AccountingComplexEnum.ShowPartyBalanceParamSearch.ZeroBalance.ToDisplay(DisplayProperty.Name),
```

... inside a projection, this sends off warning flags as Linq2EF needs to compose projections down to SQL so methods/extensions like `ToDisplay` won't be understood. Instead, since this is based solely on the Credit/Debit amounts, I'd move this to be computed by the property in the view model:

```
select new PartyDeptorAndCreditorViewModel
{
    PartyId = p.Id,
    FullName = p.FullName,
    PhoneNo = p.PartyPhones
        .Where(p => p.IsActive)
        .Select(p => p.Phone)
        .FirstOrDefault(),
    ProjectId = vg.Voucher.ProjectId,
    AccountId = vg.AccountId.Value,
    Creditor = vg.Credit,
    Deptor = vg.Debit,
    Balance = vg.Credit - vg.Debit,
    VoucherDate = vg.Voucher.VoucherDate,
    VoucherRegisterDate = vg.Voucher.VoucherDate
};
```

Then in the view model:

```
[Serializable]
public class PartyDebtorAndCreditorViewModel
{
    // ... 
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }

    public string BalanceType 
    {
        get 
        { 
             return Balance < 0 
                ? AccountingComplexEnum.ShowPartyBalanceParamSearch.Deptor.ToDisplay(DisplayProperty.Name) 
                : Balance > 0
                    ? AccountingComplexEnum.ShowPartyBalanceParamSearch.Creditor.ToDisplay(DisplayProperty.Name) 
                    : AccountingComplexEnum.ShowPartyBalanceParamSearch.ZeroBalance.ToDisplay(DisplayProperty.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: .Select(v => new { 
        ProjectId = v.Voucher.ProjectId, 
        VoucherDate = v.Voucher.VoucherDate
     })' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().

Comment: Just tested and nope, that projection is not allowed... If Voucher isn't a particularly large entity then it shouldn't impact the query performance. If it is a large chunk of data to bring back just for the two columns you might be able to project the details prior to the group by.  Have you inspected the SQL you are currently generating and seeing a particular performance impact?

Comment: Steve Py, how can I rich Voucher Item? voucher and JournalLine have a relation, (1-n)
vocher(1)->JournalLiner(n)