# How can I convert a SQL query to a Linq expression for a Join on with various conditions in EF Core 6?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, ef-core-6.0

This is my SQL query I'm trying to convert:

```
SELECT TOP (10) 
    t1.ProductName, t2.ProductName, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT t1.OrderId) AS num_orders
FROM 
    Reports t1 
JOIN
    Reports t2 ON t1.OrderId = t2.OrderId
               AND t1.ProductId < t2.ProductId
GROUP BY
    t1.ProductName, t2.ProductName
ORDER BY 
    num_orders DESC
```

As you can see, in the "on", the `orderId` must be the same and also, the `productId` of one must be less than the other.

This is what I have achieved so far (very incomplete):

```
var reportData = await (from t1 in this.Context.Reports 
                        join t2 in this.Context.Reports 
                             on t1.OrderIdequals t2.OrderId
                        where t1.ProductId < t2.ProductId
                        into GroupedData
                        orderby GroupedData.Key
                        select new 
                        {
                           GroupedData
                        }).ToListAsync();
```

I get an error if I put an expression with an "and" in the "on" and I have tried to do it in a separate "where", but it still doesn't work.

Also the select is incomplete because I have not yet managed to get all the above code to work, so don't give it any importance.

The closest I've come to getting it to work for me I got the same error this person gets: [How can I use Linq expression for Join with GroupBy in EF Core 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67455443/how-can-i-use-linq-expression-for-join-with-groupby-in-ef-core-3-1)

This is the page I have used to search for information, but it does not show what I am looking for:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/complex-query-operators

I have also used [Linqer](http://www.sqltolinq.com/) and [this repository of SQL to Linq](https://github.com/ganeshkamath89/SQL2LINQConvertor), but I can't get them to work, I'm a junior :(

Could someone help me or recommend me where to look for information?

Comment: Isn't `COUNT(DISTINCT t1.OrderId)` always equal to `1`? Are you sure the query is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
           var reportData = (from t1 in Context.Reports
                             join t2 in Context.Reports on t1.OrderId equals t2.OrderId
                             select new { t1 = t1, t2 = t2 }
                 ).Where(x => x.t1.ProductId < x.t2.ProductId)
                  .GroupBy(x => new { t1Id = x.t1.ProductId, t2Id = x.t2.ProductId })
                  .Select(x => new { t1ProductName = x.First().t1.ProductName, x.First().t2.ProductName, num_Orders = x.Select(y => y.t1.OrderId).Distinct().Count()})
                  .OrderByDescending(x => x.num_Orders);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! This solution did not work for me, it told me in the "Where" that t1 and t2 was not defined in that scope. Perhaps I have missed something to add. Even so I was able to fix the query, I appreciate it :)

Comment: I fixed the typos.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
var result = (from t1 in Reports
             join t2 in Reports on t1.OrderId equals t2.OrderId
             where t1.ProductId < t2.ProductId
             group new { t1, t2 } by new { t1.ProductName, t2.ProductName } into g
             let numOrders = g.Select(x => x.t1.OrderId).Distinct().Count()
             orderby numOrders descending
             select new
             {
                 ProductName1 = g.Key.ProductName,
                 ProductName2 = g.Key.ProductName2,
                 NumOrders = numOrders
             }).Take(10);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I had problems with the "let", I have modified your solution a bit and I get what I want.
I will sort and select the top 10 by code.
I have added my final solution in the question in the "Edit" section. Thank you very much!